# pybojc and PyObjC-core installed

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use pyautogui in virtual environment and I have already installed PyObjC and pyobjc-core and it still wants me to install these two again.

```
Package                                           Version
------------------------------------------------- -------
asgiref                                           3.3.1  
Django                                            3.1.3  
image                                             1.5.33 
MouseInfo                                         0.1.3  
Pillow                                            8.0.1  
pip                                               19.2.3 
PyAutoGUI                                         0.9.52 
PyGetWindow                                       0.0.9  
PyMsgBox                                          1.0.9  
pynput                                            1.7.1  
pyobjc                                            7.0    
pyobjc-core                                       7.0    

Mac Version:10.15.6 
python:3.8.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem, the reason do not know, I also tried a few online methods, the final effect is to delete reinstall.
My version of Python is 3.8.So go to the directory down here

`/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`

Delete the `pybojc` 、`pyobjc-core`and `pyobjc-framework-xxx`in this directory,Reexecute command

```
pip3 install pyobjc
pip3 install pyobjc-core
```

The message after success

```sh
$ pip list | grep py
pynput                                            1.7.2
pynput-robocorp-fork                              1.7.2
pyobjc                                            7.1
pyobjc-core                                       7.1
pyobjc-framework-Accessibility                    7.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts                         7.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook                      7.1
pyobjc-framework-AdServices                       7.1
pyobjc-framework-AdSupport                        7.1
...
```

```
pip show pyobjc
Name: pyobjc
Version: 7.1
Summary: Python<->ObjC Interoperability Module
Home-page: https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc
Author: Ronald Oussoren
Author-email: pyobjc-dev@lists.sourceforge.net
License: MIT License
Location: /Users/luomingyang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
Requires: pyobjc-framework-AdSupport, pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices
```